# get error The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type

Tags: javascript, angular

In the Angular2 when i was try to execute the below code i got the error

```
var intVal = function(i) {
    return typeof i === 'string'
    ? i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1
    : typeof i === 'number'
        ? i
        : 0;
};
```

**error**

> The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any',
>   'number' or an enum type.

How to fix this error?

Comment: what are you exactly trying to achieve ?

Comment: How do you call this function ? It seems to work for me. BTW, you may be interested in [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: You are doing * 1 on the string and it doesn't make sense to * 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you use `i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1`. `replace` returns a string.

Try using `+i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1` to see ?

Comment: And for information, all is in your error code : *The **left-hand side** of an **arithmetic operation** must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.* literally means `What is on the left side of your arithmetic operation (here *) is not a number`

Comment: Well nice, but the problem is on his computer, not yours ! I'm trying to correct his error, and that's what one should do to do so

Comment: You misunderstood me. Try `'127' * 1` and `+'127' * 1` in the console and see that it changes nothing, the problem isn't here.

Comment: Oh ! Then his problem is that `i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')` doesn't return a number !

Comment: So it'll return `NaN`, it won't crash.